# Ожидание выполнения асинхронной задачи

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность

Есть задача T. Необходимо запустить ее в рамках планировщика и дождаться ее выполнения. Есть ли какое-то существенное отличие между такими 2 вариантами:

```
T.Start(_scheduler)
await T.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

и

```
T.RunSynchronously(_scheduler)
```

Будет ли запуск по второму варианту приводить к блокировке потока на время ожидания, а также дополнительно к этому использовать ресурсы планировщика? В случае с первым вариантом, как я понимаю, поток не блокируется во время ожидания 
 окончания  задачи, выполняющейся в рамках планировщика, но я, возможно, заблуждаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously?view=netframework-4.7#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_RunSynchronously_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_), при вызове `RunSynchronously`

> If the target scheduler does not support running this task on the current thread, the task will be scheduled for execution on the scheduler, and the current thread will block until the task has completed execution.

Таким образом, текущий поток будет заблокирован до окончания работы задачи в любом случае.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А нет ли какой то возможности не блокировать поток на время ожидания? В рамках выполнения задачи внутри шедулера один из потоков будет заблокирован так или иначе(в момент непосредственного выполнения), есть ли какие-то варианты?

Comment: @Sleeeper: Это сильно зависит от задачи. Например, если задача типа чтения из сети (`new HttpClient().GetAsync()`) или создана через `TaskCompletionSource`, то она не занимает никакого потока. Но такие задачи создаются уже «горячими», запущенными.

Comment: @Sleeeper: а какую проблему вы решаете? Как у вас создаётся T?

Comment: Задача заключается в последовательной обработке задач согласно принципам FIFO. То есть в рамках очереди мне нужно последовательно обрабатывать задачи. Асинхронный вариант IProducerConsumer Вы мне подсказали в рамках другого ответа, то есть ожидание появления новой задачи поток не блокирует. Также хотелось бы, чтобы ожидание выполнения задачи также не приводило к излишней блокировке. По поводу TaskCompletionSource обдумаю...

Comment: То есть в принципе я могу обернуть Таск в TaskCompletionSource, но мне в любом случае нужно будет сделать SetResult, соответственно в исполняемом действии надо либо иметь ссылку на TaskCompletionSource, или делать событие, что выглядит немного костыльно.

Comment: @Sleeeper: Смотрите. Если задача привязана к процессору (например, это длинное вычисление или преобразование данных), то она всё равно будет занимать _какой-то_ поток: ведь где-то процессор должен её выполнять! А если это задача, не привязанная к процессору (дождаться данных из сети, например), то её можно написать так, чтобы она вовсе никакого потока не занимала. Вот.

Comment: Да, процессорное время будет заниматься в любом случае, однако не будет ли еще дополнительно блокироваться другой поток только на пустой ожидание завершения задачи(исполнение которой как раз использует процессорное время и блокирует поток)?

Comment: @Sleeeper: `await` и есть неблокирующее ожидание

Comment: Спасибо! Я как раз это и пытался понять. А RunSynchronously блокирующее?

Comment: @Sleeeper: Да, и ответ именно про это. Поэтому используйте `await`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!